# Computing a distribution sum

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, distribution-theory

I want to compute the distribution sum of 
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}ne^{inx}.$$

Now, this looks awfully familiar to

$$\sum_{n=-N}^{N}e^{inx}=S_{N}[\delta](x)$$

which follows from the fact that, for $\delta\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T})$, we have $\hat{\delta}(n)=1/2\pi$, so

$$S_{N}[\delta](x)=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{\delta}(n)e^{inx}.$$

Is there a "standard procedure" for computing these?

I know I have to find $L\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{T})$ such that $$\sum_{n=-N}^{N}ne^{inx}=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{L}(n)e^{inx}$$

Comment: The sum is given by
$\cos\left(N x\right) + \cot\left(x/2\right)\sin\left(N x\right)$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}nr^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^{-n}$$ for $r=e^{ix}$ and the sums are known.

Comment: @SimpleArt The sums aren't known to me.